# log4j properties file

Tags: java, log4j

I see this is a properties file

```
log4j.logger.com.asd=DEBUG, @@app.name@@
log4j.logger.com.asd.@@xyz.cad.name.lcase@@.truck=DEBUG, @@app.name@@
```

is "@@" a wildcard notation?

Comment: never mind, I figured it out. It's a variable notation

Comment: so you can post your answer and accept it. it's useful for other users to see it's already solved. thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, `@@` is not syntax for wildcards but rather denotes a variable. Cheers!